# Automatic reposting from one telegram channel to another

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

So, I'm trying to make a simple bot that will endlessly monitor the appearance of new posts on a given telegram channel to repost them to another.

I tried the telethon library for this and have already been disappointed. The telegram account used for the bot is constantly unlogged on my devices. Although I have already entered the number and confirmed the code in telethon.
I suspect the problem is in my code, so I'm asking for help.

```
async def find_new_post(current_directory, my_channel_name, my_channel_url, my_channel_id, chat_entity, api_id, api_hash, client):

    # Get the messages from the chat
    messages = await client.get_messages(chat_entity, limit=10)
    for message in messages:
        print(message.id, message.text)
            

async def main():
    coroutines = []

    client = TelegramClient(api_number, api_id, api_hash)

    client.start()

    try:
        for channel in channels:
            my_channel_name = channel["name"] 
            my_channel_url = channel["url"] 
            my_channel_id = channel["id"] 
            channels_repost_from = channel.get("repost_from", []) 
           

            for channel_repost_from_name in channels_repost_from:
                chat_entity = client.get_entity(channel["name"])
                coroutines.append(find_new_post(current_directory, my_channel_name, my_channel_url, my_channel_id, chat_entity, api_id, api_hash, client))


        await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)

    finally:
        client.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```